# Duplicate XCode Project but same executable on iPhone

Tags: xcode, projects

I need to develop two similar projects so, after I developed the first one, I copied the project folder, I renamed the folder, I renamed the project with the Project->Rename... function.
Everything works fine but when I run&debug my second project I see that the first one project disappear and it is substituted by the second one.
Even on the /Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications the first one folder is deleted and the second one is created.
I suppose that the two projects still share some info so they are builded to the same target (of course the XCode Targets are different).
Same behavior with a real device.

Where is the mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't update your PRODUCT_NAME in your build settings. This is what EXECUTABLE_NAME is based on, which is what's causing your problem.

Comment: Yes I have thought about it but inside my app Target Info the value of the key "Product Name" (inside the Packaging group) is different.
I supposed that this value is the one used inside the info.plist file for the ${PRODUCT_NAME} and ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} variables.
Is this the mistake?
If it is, where I have to change those values?
Thanks.

Comment: I FOUND IT!
It needs to change even the "Bundle identifier" inside the info.plist!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the first project as a project template to the second project.  Here is an outline of the steps needed: http://guides.macrumors.com/Creating_Xcode_project_templates